# How to set up FreeBSD for my region?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, locale, keyboard-layout, timezone

I'm currently installing FreeBSD. I'm at the "Time Zone Selector" screen. I don't know what should I choose. Normally, since I live in Quebec (Canada), I choose Eastern time GMT -5, but there is no such option. Should I choose "Atlantic Ocean" or "America -- North And South" or UTC or something else?

During the installation, I also had to choose which keyboard layout; I took French Canadian, but some of my keyboard's buttons don't give the expected result. There was no Canadian Multilingual option. How to set up Canadian Multilingual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-post.html#BSDINSTALL-TIMEZONE), after you select a region, a list with countries in that region will pop up. My guess would be America, however, you can always return back to the list of regions if you were wrong.

If you want to alter the timezone later on, you can run `tzsetup` or, if you want to do it manually, search the directory `/usr/share/zoneinfo` for the timezone of your preference and copy this file to `/etc/localtime`. Thus:

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Toronto /etc/localtime
```

Concerning keymaps and localisation, you could look over the [handbook page](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/using-localization.html) and see to what extend this helps you.

**Remark:**
I gave the above answer, as FreeBSD 9 changed installers and does not yet have the ability to get back to those menus. It will shortly, however. I am not sure if the old installer (`sysinstall`) is available. Nevertheless, I would not use it, as I am not sure in what condition it is. However, according to one of the comments the new installer (`bsdinstall`) can already be used for this specific function, by running `bsdinstall time`.

Comment: Is there a way once FreeBSD installed to get back in those menu, or i have to switch time with command?

Comment: Sure, let me alter the answer.

Comment: You can change the timezone later by running `tzsetup` or `bsdinstall time`

Comment: @RolandSmith Does that already work? I understood it did not as of the sysinstall situation, but great!

Comment: For just changing the timezone, 'tzsetup' is the best option. 'bsdinstall time' sets some other things as well. Read the relevant manual pages.